# Cannot use a constant IV key and a produced ENCRYPT_KEY in php mcrypt

Tags: php, mcrypt

I know that a constant IV key is wrong and a random key must be generated. I, however need this as I have been assigned to do this. I have searched all over the net on how to deal with this but failed. My code is below, and any advice will be greatly apprecieted.

Here's the whole code together with the functions

```
define('ENCRYPTION_KEY', 'ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ==');    //Encryption KEY

 // Encrypt Function
 function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $key)
 {
    //Do Not Put ENCRYPTION_KEY here
    $encrypt = serialize($encrypt);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
    //$iv = ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==');

    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $encrypt, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
    $passcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypt.$mac, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $encoded = base64_encode($passcrypt).'|'.base64_encode($iv);

    return $encoded; //return base64_encode($encoded).':'.$iv;
 }

// Decrypt Function
function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $key)
{
    $decrypt = explode('|', $decrypt);
    $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
    $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);

if(strlen($iv) !== mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC))
{ 
    return false; 
}

$key = pack('H*', $key);
$decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
$mac = substr($decrypted, -64);
$decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -64);
$calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $decrypted, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));

if($calcmac !== $mac)
{ 
    return false; 
}

$decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);

return $decrypted;
}

echo '<h1>Sample Encryption</h1>';

$data = 'Patrick';
$encrypted_data = mc_encrypt($data, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
echo '<h2>Example #1: String Data</h2>';
echo 'Data to be Encrypted: ' . $data . '<br/>';
echo 'Encrypted Data: ' . $encrypted_data . '<br/>';
echo 'Decrypted Data: ' . mc_decrypt($encrypted_data, ENCRYPTION_KEY) . '</br>';
```

If i use that I get the error

Warning: pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit I in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample1\test.php on line 24

and when I use the

```
$iv = ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==');
```

Instead of this

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
```

while they have both

```
define('ENCRYPTION_KEY', 'd0a7e7997b6d5fcd55f4b5c32611b87cd923e88837b63bf2941ef819dc8ca282');    //Encryption KEY
```

this is the error

```
Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample1\test.php on line 26
```

Comment: if you use: $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); you will see that you need a string that is 32 bytes long. Set $iv to be **any** string that is 32 bytes long and it will work correctly. You also need the $key to be a 'hexadecimal' string. Your code works fine with these changes.

Comment: Actually ryan the IV code that must be used is this one `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==` and no other IV key besides that. How will I do it?

Comment: Ok, the issue is that IV, when decoded is 16 bytes long. You need 32 bytes. The interesting thing is that it is just binary zeroes so you could just concatenate it with itself to give you the required length. The other interesting issue is that the encoded base64 password when converted back to a hex string does **not** match the hex password you supplied. I assume this is not the original code. Will this routine only be used to encrypt/decrypt new data?

Answer (score 2):

This is working and tested code on PHP 5.3.18. **[Demonstration at Viper-7](http://viper-7.com/RbYCJN)**

1) It uses the required base64 encoded 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==', as the IV ('salt'), which when converted back to a string is 16 bytes of binary zeroes.  As we need 32 bytes i just concatenate it with itself to make the required length.

2) There are two supplied keys:

1) base64 encoded: 'ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ==', which is a 'typical' high quality password string that is 16 bytes long. This needs to converted to a hex string for the encryption functions.

2) The hexadecimal literal: 'd0a7e7997b'...

Please note: The supplied keys, as hex strings,  are **not equal to each other**!

This does not affect the routines, just be aware that the same key must be used to encrypt / decrypt.

The routines:

```
 // Encrypt Function - $key must be a Hexadecimal String
 function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $key) {
    //Do Not Put ENCRYPTION_KEY here
    $encrypt = serialize($encrypt);

    // $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $iv = base64_decode(ENCRYPTION_IV); // convert back to binary string
    $actualIV = $iv . $iv; // As it is 16 bytes of binary characters just double it

    $key = pack('H*', $key); // convert key back to binary string
    $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $encrypt, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
    $passcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypt.$mac, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $actualIV);
    $encoded = base64_encode($passcrypt).'|'.base64_encode($iv);
    return $encoded;
 }
```

Note that '$actualIV' is just a 'trick' to get the 32 bytes required. However, it will work if different 16 byte IV's are used.

**Caveats:** It is important that different (random) IV's are used when encrypting otherwise identical messages encrypt to the same ciphertext when the same key is used. To use 16 byte IV's in the routine i would be tempted to generate a random IV and just use the first 16 bytes of it concatenated to itself as is used currently.

i.e. replace this code:

```
$iv = base64_decode(ENCRYPTION_IV); // convert back to binary string
```

with:

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
$iv = substr($iv, 0, 16);
```

**CBC mode and 'Padding Oracle Attacks'**
It looks as though this is not an issue if you use PHP exclusively. There may be issues decrypting on different systems. This link explains the issues: [Cryptography/DES-PHP-Block-Padding-in-mcrypt.html](http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/DES-PHP-Block-Padding-in-mcrypt.html)

```
// Decrypt Function - - $key must be a Hexadecimal String
function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $key) {
    $decrypt = explode('|', $decrypt);
    $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
    $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);

    $actualIV = $iv . $iv; // make it long enough and match the original IV used.
    if(strlen($actualIV) !== mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)){ return false; }

    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $actualIV));
    $mac = substr($decrypted, -64);
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -64);
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $decrypted, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
    if($calcmac!==$mac) { return false; }
    $decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);
    return $decrypted;
}
```

Note that '$iv' is concatenated with itself to get the 32 bytes required.

Defined keys:

```
define('ENCRYPTION_B64KEY', 'ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ==');    //Encryption KEY
define('ENCRYPTION_IV', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==');
define('ENCRYPTION_HEXKEY', 'd0a7e7997b6d5fcd55f4b5c32611b87cd923e88837b63bf2941ef819dc8ca282');    //Encryption KEY
```

Examples using both supplied keys:

```
echo '<h1>Sample Encryption</h1>';

$data = 'Patrick';
echo '<h2>Example #1: Using base64 encoded key (ENCRYPTION_B64KEY)</h2>';

$b64HexKey = bin2hex(base64_decode(ENCRYPTION_B64KEY));
$encrypted_data = mc_encrypt($data, $b64HexKey);
echo 'Data to be Encrypted: ' . $data . '<br/>';
echo 'Encrypted Data: ' . $encrypted_data . '<br/>';
echo 'Decrypted Data: ' . mc_decrypt($encrypted_data, $b64HexKey) . '</br>';

echo '<h2>Example #2 using Hexadecimal Key (ENCRYPTION_HEXKEY)</h2>';

$hexKey = ENCRYPTION_HEXKEY;
$encrypted_data = mc_encrypt($data, $hexKey);
echo 'Data to be Encrypted: ' . $data . '<br/>';
echo 'Encrypted Data: ' . $encrypted_data . '<br/>';
echo 'Decrypted Data: ' . mc_decrypt($encrypted_data, $hexKey) . '</br>';
```

Output from the above:

```
Sample Encryption

Example #1: Using base64 encoded key (ENCRYPTION_B64KEY)

Data to be Encrypted: Patrick
Encrypted Data: /7qKjoPnNiGveTHo0NnkXfSLFIHE72De1q85QWI/d16j4BzLaqIR7jpap0J2wCdHYgK+IS4Zf1OpZorK9iGnPErkh+owjkoEo/dejHxUaVxOS03+Uqti8i13aGeB6wAU|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
Decrypted Data: Patrick
Example #2 using Hexadecimal Key (ENCRYPTION_HEXKEY)

Data to be Encrypted: Patrick
Encrypted Data: iAyCpfnOHUeHKHT+BIra2TZbRlLJfXKAO5pRGbmKvLyTOlzr9L6IBRI8ZuDsGVdZym26Qd89hKZxnVPbBSsOktCaztF9akZA8iPa3r0jvgISFldRDdHx8CZyd+GfR9BV|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
Decrypted Data: Patrick
```